# Discrepancy in plotting mean and CI using `stat_smooth` vs coefficients from a linear model in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, mixed-models

I am trying to plot mean and 95% confidence interval for a normally distributed dataset. I tried two ways: Using the `stat_summary`
function in ggplot2 and then using the `lm` models, extracting the coefficients to plot. However, I get two different graphs. Why do I find this discrepancy?

Plotting using the inbuilt `ggplot2` mean and CI

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x.axis = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 50),
y.axis = rnorm(1000, 1.2, 2))

ggplot(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), color = "gray")+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.3, colour="black") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "black", geom ="point", size = 5,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + geom_hline(yintercept = 1)
```

[image]

Plotting using model fitting

```
mod <- lm(y.axis~x.axis, df)
summary(mod)
confint(mod)

summary_df <- summary(mod)$coefficients %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D")) %>%
  dplyr::rename(y.axis = Estimate) %>%
  mutate(ymin = y.axis - 1.96 * `Std. Error`,
         ymax = y.axis + 1.96 * `Std. Error`)

ggplot(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis,), data = df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), color = "grey", data = df, inherit.aes=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x.axis, y = y.axis), color = 'black', data = summary_df,size = 5, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = x.axis, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,y = NULL), data = summary_df, inherit.aes=FALSE, width = 0.3) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + geom_hline(yintercept = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the output of `lm`. When there are discrete variables, one is chosen as the baseline (A in this case) and the others are expressed relative to it. If you add the mean of A back onto B, C, and D, the graphs should look pretty much the same. `stat_summary` probably does something more sophisticated than +-1.96sd for the error bars, so they will be a bit different anyway.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Oh! Is there an easy way to add the Intercept value back to the other points but not to `A`? I want to see what the differences between `stat_summary` and `lm` output woudl be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember than `stat_summary` works out its summary function at each x axis point individually, so you have a unique standard error for each error bar. Also, you are using `mean_cl_boot`, which uses a bootstrap method to calculate the standard error and might be slightly different each time.

Calculating the mean and standard error for each letter A, B, C and D individually is conceptually different from the standard error of the estimates from a linear model, which are calculated from the variance-covariance matrix. The standard errors will be the same for each level of a factor variable in this case.

We can see the predicted mean and confidence intervals from a linear model like this:

```r
(preds_lm <- (lm(y.axis ~ x.axis, data = df) |>
  predict(se = TRUE, newdata = list(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D"))) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  cbind(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D")) |>
  within(y.min <- fit - qnorm(0.975) * se.fit) |>
  within(y.max <- fit + qnorm(0.975) * se.fit) |>
  within(y <- fit))[c(5, 8, 6, 7)])
#>   x.axis        y     y.min    y.max
#> 1      A 1.116479 0.8710536 1.361904
#> 2      B 1.492055 1.2466300 1.737480
#> 3      C 1.235067 0.9896423 1.480493
#> 4      D 1.085421 0.8399962 1.330847
```

This is very similar, but *not identical* to the results you are getting using `mean_cl_boot`, (inside `stat_summary`), which are as follows:

```r
do.call(rbind, tapply(df$y.axis, df$x.axis, mean_cl_boot))
#>          y      ymin     ymax
#> A 1.116479 0.8881777 1.343985
#> B 1.492055 1.2355448 1.725858
#> C 1.235067 0.9627651 1.480975
#> D 1.085421 0.8463755 1.330476
```

If you want to plot the `lm` results, you can do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x.axis)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y.axis), color = "gray") +
  geom_errorbar(data = preds_lm, width = 0.3,
                aes(ymin = y.min, ymax = y.max)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y), data = preds_lm, size = 5, color = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 7/5)  + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1)
```

[image]

Note that although this looks nearly identical to your original plot, this is largely due to the samples all being drawn from a normal distribution with the same variance, and you might see very different results in smaller samples, or cases where the variance is different between factor levels.

<sup>Created on 2023-06-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. I'm curious to know what the limitations of this method may be? I tried implementing something similar for a nested random effects model, but R dosen't seem to quite like it. Any thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546139/model-predictions-for-a-nested-random-effects-model-in-r