# Model predictions for a nested random effects model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I am trying to fit a mixed model with random effects: `lmer` model to the dataset df based on [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510072/7258020). However, I run into an error that says invalid "times" argument. Any suggestions on how to fix it.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x.axis = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 50),
                 y.axis = rnorm(1000, 1.2, 2),
                 rf1 = rep(c("W","X","Y","Z"), times = 50),
                 rf2 = rep(c("1","2","1","2"), times = 50))

(preds_lm <- (lmer(y.axis ~ x.axis + (1|rf1/rf2), data = df) |>
            predict(se = TRUE, newdata = list(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                                              rf1 = c("W","X","Y","Z"),
                                              rf2 = c("1","2"))) |>
            as.data.frame() |>
            cbind(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D")) |>
            within(y.min <- fit - qnorm(0.975) * se.fit) |>
            within(y.max <- fit + qnorm(0.975) * se.fit) |>
            within(y <- fit))[c(5, 8, 6, 7)])
```

> Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument In addition: Warning
> message: In predict.merMod(lmer(y.axis ~ x.axis + (1 | rf1/rf2), data
> = df),  :   unused arguments ignored

Answer (score 1):

When debugging, it's useful to "un-pipe" your code so you can see where things are going wrong (I think there are some helper packages for this but don't remember what they are ...)

```r
p1 <- lmer(y.axis ~ x.axis + (1|rf1/rf2), data = df)
## fine
p2 <- predict(p1, se = TRUE, newdata = list(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                                  rf1 = c("W","X","Y","Z"),
                                  rf2 = c("1","2")))
```

So we can see that the problem occurs in `predict`. The first obvious problem is that the `predict` method for `merMod` objects (i.e. the models created by `lmer`: see `?predict.merMod`) don't have an `se` argument (if you want standard errors on predictions you might need to take a look at a package like `ggeffects`); this causes the "unused arguments ignored" warning.

However, taking `se = TRUE` out still gives us the same error ... but making `newdata` a data frame rather than a list seems to work (this is also specified in `?predict.merMod`).

```r
newdat <- data.frame(x.axis = c("A","B","C","D"), 
                                              rf1 = c("W","X","Y","Z"),
                                              rf2 = c("1","2"))
p2 <- predict(p1, newdata = newdat)
```

However, the rest of your code won't work because (unlike the `predict` method for linear models), `predict()` doesn't return a list with predictions and standard errors.

Looking more closely, I don't think `ggpredict` will do what you want. You can use the [recipe from the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme) for computing SEs of predictions (note that this **only incorporates uncertainty in the fixed effects** — the rest is a can of worms).

```r
mm <- model.matrix(delete.response(terms(p1)), newdat)
se.fit <- sqrt(diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(p1),mm)))
```

Alternately, you could use parametric bootstrapping (**slow** but accurate):

```r
bb <- bootMer(p1, function(m) predict(m, newdat), nsim = 1000, seed = 101)
confint(bb)
     2.5 %   97.5 %
1 0.7713446 1.451530
2 1.1581111 1.825785
3 0.9152968 1.570501
4 0.7163327 1.446359
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. A followup on `bootMer`, how is it different from the `boot_summary` in the package `boot.pval`. Also, is there an easy way to get the estimates, p-val, F-val etc in the `bootMer` package like in the traditional `lme4`?

Comment: Neither of these is a very quick answer. The first is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  For the second: you can get parametric bootstrap p-values with `pbktrtest::PBmodcomp`. But again the variety of statistical issues are a little deeper than you might expect (parametric vs (nested) nonparametric bootstrap, Wald vs likelihood-based p-values, etc.). It would probably be good to post an example and explain exactly what you're looking for, e.g. since you *can* get p-val/F-value etc from `lmerTest`, is there a particular reason you prefer bootstrap ests?

Comment: PS `boot_summary()` uses `bootMer` internally ...